# Mac App Sandbox testing - how remove existing folder access permissions

Tags: macos, cocoa

I'm currently adding Sandboxing support to my app.

Having give permission to my app to access a folder (by dragging it onto my Window) and I would now like to revoke that permission so that I can retest what happens before that permission is given.

How can I do that?

I'm not yet using URL bookmarks, and yet the permission persists across restarts of the application. I don't know if this is because it's a folder rather than a file?

Answer (score 0):

Before you change the permissions of file or folder, you must store the current one for later use. I have never seen a method or system-call to restore previous permissions after a change.